# how to create Spring component for SpringContextProcessor with Nifi

Tags: spring-integration, apache-nifi

I was trying to follow Oleg's demo in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F98NLule18I&t=1909s

And I pulled his si-demo from https://github.com/olegz/si-demo

But in Nifi 1.6.0, when SpringContextProcessor is configed with si-demo classpath and toNifiOnly.xml the processor yanks InvocationTargetException, and processor won't be properly initialized!

Are there any other demos or examples for creating a spring component for Nifi? Or how to fix this?

Here is the error message in log file:

```html
2018-06-02 09:26:28,040 ERROR [Monitor Processore Lifecycle Thread-2] o.a.nifi.spring.SpringContextProcessor SpringContextProcessor[id=bc3dbcab-0163-1000-4b77-af4eab0c7c46] Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor374.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
 at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
 at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
 at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
 at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.lambda$initiateStart$3(StandardProcessorNode.java:1455)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed while initializing Spring Application Context
 at org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextProcessor.initializeSpringContext(SpringContextProcessor.java:239)
 ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate Spring Application Context. Config path: 'fromNifiOnly.xml'; Classpath: [[file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/commons-logging-1.2.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/camel-spring-2.16.2.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/camel-core-2.16.2.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/si-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/]]
 at org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextFactory.createSpringContextDelegate(SpringContextFactory.java:92)
 at org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextProcessor.initializeSpringContext(SpringContextProcessor.java:236)
 ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextFactory.createSpringContextDelegate(SpringContextFactory.java:80)
 ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
 at org.apache.nifi.spring.bootstrap.SpringContextDelegate.<init>(SpringContextDelegate.java:72)
 ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I am no longer with NiFi but don't mind helping. Could you please provide a more detailed stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your relay Oleg! Here is the log:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate Spring Application Context. Config path: 'fromNifiOnly.xml'; Classpath: [[file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/commons-logging-1.2.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/camel-spring-2.16.2.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/shuo/Projects/sts-workspace/si-demo/target/deps/spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar,

Comment: I will paste full error on the main problem definition

Comment: I run mvn clean install on the repo pulled, but those xml configs are not genereated in target/deps

Comment: If I copy xmls to deps folder, the SpringContextProcessor can run, the processor won't be initiated

Comment: It seems I need to copy all the xml files to deps, and then it is beginning to work

Comment: The support for SpringContextProcessor is up to 4.2.13.RELEASE, from 4.3.0 it breaks. Do you have any suggestion on modifying SpringContextProcessor to support the latest spring integration?

Comment: That is correct, you were missing entries from he classpath including spring itself as it could not find ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out later that it is necessary to copy all the xml files to the deps folder to let it run!